# Shimano Dura-Ace 1st Generation Brake adjustment

Tags: brakes, shimano

I am trying to get my rear brakes to work properly but I do not understand how it works.

I dissembled the caliper, cleaned each component (since the brake raked (?)). But now I have the problem that the side where the brake cable attaches is stiff and only the other side moves properly. I can provide two pictures of how I reassembled the brake

[image]

From another perspective:

[image]

On that second picture only the right side of the brake moves the other one does not when I pull the lever. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: the "spring" like piece of metal, sometimes loses it push, and you need to stretch it wider, then get it back into position, this will pull the brake apart, allowing you to squeeze it back together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I do not get the brake cable back in so I have to wait till monday for a try. One thing I would like to ask additionally. If I pull the last bold to tight the brakes do not move anymore at all. Should I "counter" that bold with another one to have a bit space between the "wings"

Comment: with no cable is your brake open wide, or does it stay closed. If closed, with no cable, are you able to open the brake with your hands? the proper way for the brake to work is to try to pull itself open at all times, and you use the cable to pull it closed.

Comment: After your advised stretch adjustment the brake is open with no cable.

Comment: Ok that means the brake should be working, once you have the cable on there you will have to test it by setting the brake up properly to the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spring is not right - its one or more of

- bent unevenly
- lost springiness with age
- pinched
- mounted not square in the retainer.

I've tried to show the difference I see here:

[image: Own work based on the photo provided by OP]

To be honest unless originality is a big thing, consider moving to a dual pivot brake caliper.  The old single pivot side pull caliper was always sub par.